# What does the html engine JavaFX uses?

Tags: browser, javafx

There is a `WebView` in JavaFX, which can render a html page (also with the css and javascript).

I wonder what the engine is it? A pure java one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoding to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm):

> The JavaFX embedded browser component is based on [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/), an open
>   source web browser engine.
>   ...

and I think it is not a pure Java.